# how do i create a base url asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

is there any way to create base url like this or something.

```
<link href="<asp:label id='baseUrl' runat='server'></asp:label>/assets/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<asp:label id='baseUrl' runat='server'></asp:label>/assets/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<asp:label id='baseUrl' runat='server'></asp:label>/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

// behind the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    baseUrl.Text = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
}
```

and to make it like this below

```
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/plugins/clockpicker/css/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use a variable? That what they are for....

Comment: Is a root relative path (`href="/assets/plugins/clockpicker/css/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css" `) not sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options

**Should work everywhere: Root relative path**

This will work no mater the technology stack.

This will resolve to the root of your application.

```
<link href="/assets/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Public property**

Set a public property on your CodeBehind page class

```
/*C# Code Behind*/
public string BaseUrl {get {return "http://127.0.0.1:8080";}}

/*HTML/.apx*/
<link href="<%=this.BaseUrl%>/assets/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<%=this.BaseUrl%>/assets/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<%=this.BaseUrl%>/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Use ~ in server controls to resolve the URL automatically** - note `runat=server`

This will also resolve to the root of your application.

```
<link runat="server" href="~/assets/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link runat="server" href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link runat="server" href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Note that from your solution you can't have multiple elements with the same ID

Answer (score 2):

If you want to link your files this way,
you have to do as follows:

```
<link id="baseUrl" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Code Behind:

```
baseUrl.Attributes.Add("href", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css");
```